# Why does a local hono build fail with "Unable to pull 'index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-service-auth-quarkus:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'"

Tags: eclipse-hono

Environment:

> Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven-3.8.2
> Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
> Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-173-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

```
mvn clean install failsafe:verify -DCI=true -Dhono.components.type=quarkus -Dhono.deviceregistry.type=mongodb -Dhono.messaging-infra.type=kafka -Dhono.commandrouting.cache=server -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn -DskipStaging=true -Pmetrics-prometheus,jaeger,run-tests
```

fails with:

> [INFO] DOCKER> [index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-infinispan-test:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]: Built image sha256:57c05
> [INFO] DOCKER> [index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-jaeger-test:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT] : Skipped building
> [INFO] Copying files to /home/achim/repos/hono/tests/target/docker/index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-service-auth-test/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/build/maven
> [INFO] Building tar: /home/achim/repos/hono/tests/target/docker/index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-service-auth-test/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tmp/docker-build.tar
> [INFO] DOCKER> [index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-service-auth-test:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]: Created docker-build.tar in 2 seconds
> [ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to pull 'index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-service-auth-quarkus:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT' from registry 'index.docker.io' : {"message":"manifest for eclipse/hono-service-auth-quarkus:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"} (Not Found: 404) [{"message":"manifest for eclipse/hono-service-auth-quarkus:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"} (Not Found: 404)]

Do I need to change the mvn parameter? Or what is required for the tests to be successfully executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven command does not activate the profile that is required for building the container images. In your case it should be

```sh
mvn clean install failsafe:verify -DCI=true -Dhono.components.type=quarkus -Dhono.deviceregistry.type=mongodb -Dhono.messaging-infra.type=kafka -Dhono.commandrouting.cache=server -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn -DskipStaging=true -Pbuild-docker-image,metrics-prometheus,jaeger,run-tests
```